# How to open popup/new tab (target="_blank") and respect mobile (and desktop too)?

Tags: html, mobile, popup, desktop, target

I have some social sharing links to share a post. This has to be in a new popup/tab/window. You know, the box we all know to share something on FB etc.

For desktop a new tab isn' necessary, so I'm using this:

```
<a href="popup-example.html" target="popup-example" onClick="javascript:open('', 'popup-example', 'height=400,width=400,resizable=no')">
```

But now I was asking myself how to make it for mobile devices..

Maybe just a php script to detect if it's desktop, than use example above. If mobile, use `<a target="_blank"`?

Would this be the right way? Or do I need a mobile hook for the Facebook app for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about trying:

```
javascript:open('http://domain.com', 'popup-example', 'height='+window.innerheight+',width='+window.innerwidth+'resizable=no')
```

This would open in a new browser window for desktop (popup) and a seperate tab for mobile?

Comment: btw: thank you! now with enough rep, i was able to upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not open a custom sized browser window on mobile devices. So you don't need a special solution to run your code in mobile devices.

Comment: Yes. You can open a new window with just `target="_blank"`. It will has the same effect with opening a window with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the late feedback! (I love this website :D) I'll edit the particular file :) Have a good one!